# Spector Pro causes explorer.exe to eat CPU cyles on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

I'm using [Spector Pro](http://www.spectorsoft.com/products/spectorpro_windows/) primarily for capturing screenshots on some Windows XP machines, as per our customer's wishes.  These machines ([Dell Optiplex 780](http://www.dell.com/ca/business/p/optiplex-780/pd?oc=o780sff_ft6&model_id=optiplex-780)) were originally shipped to us with Windows 7 Pro.  I installed our software, as well as Spector Pro and a few other third party applications, and everything worked as expected.

After being informed that our customer requires these machines use Windows XP, we performed the OS downgrade, reinstalled our software, and reinstalled all of the third party software.  Now, whenever Spector Pro is taking screenshots, explorer.exe uses an entire CPU core, degrading the performance of everything else.

I have already tried changing the BIOS settings so that the HDD is in legacy mode, as I suspect the issue is writing the screenshots to the HDD, however this didn't solve the problem.  Lowering the quality or frequency of the screenshots is also not an option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video card drivers were out of date.  Updating them reduced the load on the CPU to such a point that the performance of our software is no longer impacted.

Comment: bizzare, but if this is the correct answer, select it as such so that others will know.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek Can't until tomorrow.  Also, I agree that it's bizarre, as we have another (beefier) machine that works fine with outdated drivers.